# Vagrant reload doesn't work, something else is running

Tags: laravel

Homestead.yaml is set up correctly:

```
folders:
- map: ~/web/sites/example
  to: /home/vagrant/sites/example

sites:
- map: example.app
  to: /home/vagrant/sites/example/public
```

and localhost is also set up correctly:

```
127.0.0.1 example.app
```

which should show the default Laravel welcome page after I use vagrant reload --provision, but it shows 'It works!' instead. Vagrant halt still shows 'It works!', so something else is running, probably from me testing something else. But I don't remember what I have done.

How do I figure out what is running? Googling "localhost folder" doesn't help. Or is something else wrong? I'm using a Mac, by the way.

Comment: I still can't figure out what's on localhost, but I figured out how to make the example project work. Apparently vagrant reload --provision doesn't work, but vagrant halt, followed by vagrant up, followed by vagrant provision works, even though the two should be the same thing? If someone can explain what happened, I would appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

To figure out what is running, you can use the [netstat](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) command, that will show you network connections.
Since you are accessing only by 127.0.0.1, you must be using this service port 80, so using `netstat -n | grep ":80"` may show you this. If you are using other port, and know it by number, you can pass this to `grep`, instead of the cited "80".